# how to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath in table view in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: objective-c

```
SliderDemoController *sliderDemoController=[[SliderDemoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sliderDemoController animated:YES];
```

i implemented this method using storyboard. but this method is not working. i want to open new controller in table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to access any view controllers which is in story board then you should use `UIStoryBoard class`.If you not sure about how to do that so, [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the link for apple document about `UIStoryBoard` and use the method  `+ (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *) storyboardBundleOrNil` to access your storyboard.
       Access your view controller with the method `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` and use the returned view controller object.Hope this helps you....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to query the `UIStoryboard` object -- setting up transitions between view controllers is what storyboards do automagically. And with storyboards, you don't need to implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` either.

If you haven't already, define a segue from the (prototype) table cell to the destination view controller (looks like that's `SliderDemoController` for you) by control-dragging. (Choose the Push segue type.) For functionality equivalent to the non-storyboard code you posted, that's all there is to it -- now tapping any row in the table will push in a `SliderDemoController`.

However, you probably want to configure that `SliderDemoController` based on which row was selected, right? Then, in your table view controller, implement `prepareForSegue:sender:`. There you can get a reference to the destination view controller (from the segue parameter) and set it up however you like.